# Problem in writing a function that reads a bunch of CSV files and assigns them to a character object

Tags: r, function, read.csv

I encountered this problem as i was solving a question where i have to create a function to read a bunch of CSV files into R and then compute the mean of a specific quanitity as an aggregate of the files specified

This is my try at creating that function. Here id is a input from the user which specifies the file name he/she wants to read

```
pollutantmean <- function(id){
    for (i in id) {
      z <- list.files()[i]
      assign(paste('data', i,sep = ''),read.csv(z))
    }
}
```

Here i was expecting that a number of objects would be created with names for example being 'data1' or "data2" but when i run pollutantmean it does'nt create any objects.

```
id <- 1:20
    for (i in id) {
      z <- list.files()[i]
      assign(paste('data', i,sep = ''),read.csv(z))
    }
```

When i run the above code it creates the objects that is specified. Why is this occuring.

Comment: Forget that the `assign` function even exists. Learn to work with lists of objects instead of putting related objects into the global environment and use functional programming. Your specific issue is scoping. `assign` assigns into the current environment by default. If that is not the global environment but a function environment, the result is lost after the function return.  Btw., many long-time members here have become tired of the "pollutantmean" assignments a long time ago.

Comment: The `assign()` function creates variables in the scope where it is called. It's creating variables in your function scope, but those values disappear when the function finishing running. Using `assign()` is frowned upon in general. It's better if your function returns a list of values rather than trying to alter objects in the environment.

Comment: @Roland thanks for the reply I am having difficult using lists properly to input different classes of objects which is why I had resorted to `assign`. May I know why assign is frowned upon in R community? Also you mentioned about using functional programming can you please elaborate on what you mean by that? **(On hacking it just shows to implement a program by the use of function)**

Answer (score -2):

The `envir` and `pos` arguments to the `assign()` function allow you to specify where to perform the assignment. In your original example the variables were created within the function environment when you were probably expecting the assignments to occur in .GlobalEnv...

```r
pollutantmean <- function(id){
    for (i in id) {
      z <- list.files()[ i ]
      assign(paste('data', i, sep = ''), read.csv(z), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}
pollutantmean(1:20)
ls()
```

While the above code *will* work, I should note that it is generally considered terrible R programming practice to use the `assign()` function. A better solution might be something like this:

```r
pollutantmean <- function(dirpath){
  results <- lapply(list.files(path = dirpath, 
                               pattern = '.*\\.csv', 
                               full.names = TRUE), 
                    read.csv)
  names(results) <- sprintf('data%s', 1:(length(results)))
  results
}
data_list <- pollutantmean('~/your-data-directory')
data_list$data1 |> head()
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, I had some questions regarding your updated code

Comment: 1) In the function `lapply` for the pattern argument you used a `., *, \\  ` can you tell me the use of these operators (my guess * is a substitution for any number of character) as I thought just using `'*csv'` would have been enough _2) In the sprintf function I am unable to understand what %s would act as a substitution for (documentation specified only the argument)_ **3) In the last line of your code you used `|> head()` what is its use**

Comment: 1) The pattern argument '.*\\.csv' is a regular expression that should match any file with the ".csv" extension; 2) correct, "%s" represents sustitution of a character string; 3) "|>" is the pipe operator. `data_list$data1 |> head()` is equivalent to `head(data_list$data1)`